# Как подставить ссылки для кнопок через атрибут target с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Проблема в следующем, у меня есть несколько кнопок на странице, и нужно каждой из кнопки подставить свою ссылку, ссылки будут находиться в отдельном файле.

У меня получилось заменить ссылку если на странице есть только одна кнопка. как можно доработать скрипт чтобы он проходился по всем кнопкам и каждой подставлял соответствующую ей ссылку?

```
function refresh(x=false){
    var y = "/new_links/";
        if (x) window.open(y, '_blank'); 

        else
        window.location.href = y;
        return false;
}
```

у кнопок соответственно есть обработчик `onclick="return refresh(true)"`  и атрибут `target="_blank"`.

я думаю что нужно собрать массив данных где будет соответствие допустим Id кнопки и ссылки которую нужно подставить, но не могу понять как это реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут есть несколько вариантов решения и зависит от того, как именно у тебя расставлены кнопки по сайту.

=== Первый вариант ===

Если кнопки находятся в определнном блоке, то достаточно будет сделать так: https://codepen.io/NocteFury/pen/wvMrgpj

В данном случае ты подписываешься на событие лишь в одном блоке, это оптимальнее, чем несколько подписок, да и управлять ими проще, так как для отписки достаточно лишь отписаться только от одной, а не хранить список из всех.
Почему это работает можешь почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling).

=== Второй вариант ===

Однако, часто бывает необходимо обработать кнопки по всему проекту. Тогда можно использовать `document.querySelectorAll()` ([ссылка на документацию по методу](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)), данный метод позволяет тебе получить список всех элементов по [селектору CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B). В данном случае тебе достаточно придумать [data-тэг](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) для своих кнопок (например `data-id`) и создать вот такой селектор: `button[data-id]`. Такой селектор означает, что нам нужны все кнопки (элемент с тегом `button`) и у которых в аттрибутах есть `data-id` (все, что указывается внутри элемента через `<name>="<value>"`):
https://codepen.io/NocteFury/pen/vYLegzJ

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, вторым вариантом воспользовался

Answer (score 0):

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper')

const buttons = [
  {
    name: 'Google',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Stackoverflow',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'LinkedIn',
    id: 3
  }
]

const links = [
  {
    href: 'https://www.google.com/',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    href: 'https://stackoverflow.com/',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    href: 'https://www.linkedin.com/',
    id: 3
  }
]

buttons.forEach(btn => {
  links.forEach(link => {
    if (btn.id === link.id) {
      let html = `
        <a class="btn" href="${link.href}" target="_blank">${btn.name}</a>
      `
      wrapper.innerHTML += html
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: Правда stackoverflow target="_blank" блокирует, так что открывайте в новом окне, а так вообще работает

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то что мне нужно. но в будущем думаю пригодится. я загружаю ссылки в разные файлы и размещаю в папке. У кнопки ссылки изначально быть не должно, она должна появляться в момент когда происходит нажатие.

Comment: Проголосуйте тогда если Вам не сложно